# tinyMCE shows html tags

Tags: jquery, razor, model-view-controller, tinymce

I'm using tinyMCE as editor on my mvc razor view engine.
My issue happens when I try to append the formatted content to specific div. It's shown as html tags instead of the formatted one.

This is the init call:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        height: 500,
        theme: 'modern',
        plugins: 'print preview fullpage paste searchreplace autolink directionality bbcode visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount spellchecker  imagetools media  link contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help',
        toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat',
        image_advtab: true,
        templates: [
          { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
          { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
        ],
        content_css: [
          '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
          '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
        ]
    });
```

and this is the JS script

```
function x () {
var content = tinyMCE.get('article').getContent();

            $('#bodyDiv').html(content)
}
```

see attached file below

A bold string in tinyMCE:
[image]

And the copied string in local div:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in this line of code:

```
var content = tinyMCE.get('article').getContent();
```

You need the body html and so you can change the previous line with:

```
var content = tinyMCE.get('article').getBody().innerHTML;
```

In the following the fixed code and a running [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01k5pLar/)

```js
function x () {
    var content = tinyMCE.get('article').getBody().innerHTML;
    $('#bodyDiv').html(content)
}
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    x();
})
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    height: 500,
    theme: 'modern',
    plugins: 'print preview fullpage paste searchreplace autolink directionality bbcode visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount spellchecker  imagetools media  link contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help',
    toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat',
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
        { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
    ],
    content_css: [
        '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
        '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
    ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js'></script>

<h1>TinyMCE Quick Start Guide</h1>
<form method="post">
    <textarea id="article">Hello, World!</textarea>
</form>
<button>Click Me</button>
<div id="bodyDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the `bbcode` plugin - the output from TinyMCE when using that plugin is not HTML but rather BBCode formatting.  If you want HTML to render in a DIV it would think it would make sense to not load the `bbcode` plugin so that TinyMCE provides you HTML.